# How can be a conservative field constraint be efficiently implemented in a continuous optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, computer-science, numerical-optimization

Suppose we have the following continuous optimization problem:

$$
\underset{x}{\mathrm{minimize}}f\left(x\right)
$$
subject to
$$
\exists X:\nabla X=Jac\left(X\right)=x
$$
where $f$ is a function $f:M_{v}\left(_{n}D_{v}\right)\rightarrow M_{v}\left(_{n}D_{v}\right)$, where $M_{v}\left(_{n}D_{v}\right)$ is essentially a $v$-dimensional matrix space over polynomial functions $\mathbb{R}^{v}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

With care and attention to detail, the matrices can be treated as vectors for certain purposes.

In other words, function $f$ is minimized subject to the constraint that $x$ is a conservative field.

Another way to write the constraint is by using the symmetry of second derivatives property, which is
$$
D_{i}f_{jk}\left(x\right)=D_{k}f_{ji}\left(x\right)
$$

How can this constraint be efficiently implemented in practice, for example in case of simple gradient descent?

It is assumed that the dimension $n$ is relatively high, such as $n=16$ and possibly higher, so that applying all the numerous constraints in brute-force fashion is undesirable.

There is an equivalent way to formulate this problem with objective function $\tilde{f}\left(X\right)$, implementation of which poses the same practical efficiency difficulties as the original problem.

Comment: Wait, don't you mean $x$ is a function $x:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ and $f$ is a functional that maps $x$ to $\mathbb R$? Otherwise I can't make sense of your question. Anyway, why not just take the scalar potential $X$ as the optimization variable and minimize $f(\nabla X)$?

Comment: @Rahul Okay, sorry, I oversimplified the problem statement, but now I corrected it. I have considered what you are suggesting, but in practice it is quite hard to implement in a computer program; it is essentially an equivalent problem with similar difficulties. I would be happy to hear a suggestion on a "trick" to efficiently solve the equivalent problem you mentioned as well.

Comment: Do you mean $\nabla X =f$ ?

Comment: @guest: No, this is not the case. $f$ acts on $x$, where $x$ is a gradient/Jacobian of $X$.

Comment: So $X$ is a scalar field, $x$ is its gradient.  How is then $x$ an element of a "matrix space"?

Comment: @guest $X$ is a vector field, so the gradient/Jacobian of it is a matrix $x$.

Comment: What is the gradient of a vector field?  Do you mean the Jacobian?  Maybe you should actually mention all this terminology in your question, because it is very non-standard.

Comment: @guest Well, yes, it is a Jacobian, but I normally take a gradient to obtain it, which is equivalent. Speaking of conservative fields, perhaps the use of gradient terminology is more familiar. But I will mention the Jacobian as well.

Comment: I still can't make sense of your problem for exactly the same reasons as before. If $f:M\to M$ (I'm writing $M$ for $M_v({}_nD_v)$), then $f(x)\in M$, so what does it mean to minimize a matrix $f(x)$? Further, how is the constraint $\nabla X=x$ equivalent to $D_if_{jk}=D_kf_{ji}$, an expression that does not mention $x$ at all? I assume these are typos, but please clarify. And when you say "it is quite hard to implement in a computer program", that all depends on what representations and algorithms you're trying to use; I might be able to help but only if you provide more context.

Comment: @Rahul (1) It is minimization of the polynomial coefficients of the image of $f$. (2) By $f_{jk}$, it is meant $f_{jk}(x)$. (3) For example, the gradient of $f(\nabla X)$ is difficult to compute numerically in terms of $X$, as both $X$ and $\nabla X$ are polynomial functions.

Comment: I give up.${}{}$